# Blank page on deploy with Google app engine PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I used Google APIs Client Library for PHP in my project. When I test on localhost it's work, but I deploy to server it's show blank page. I don't know what should I do. May I set config not complete.

This is **app.yaml**

```
application: lookatgafe
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /img
  static_dir: img

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

And this one when I link PHP in my project it download PHP file to my computer doesn't open a webpage.

Can someone help me out?

// sorry for my English...

Thank you!

Comment: What is being logged in the logs?

Comment: on deploy? no error has found. Its work normally

Answer (score 2):

After you have deployed the app, and have attempted to access the site in your browser. Once you get the *blank* page.

Go to the Logs screen on the AppEngine section for your project of the Google Cloud Developers Console (https://cloud.google.com/console).

[image: Logs screen on the AppEngine section of the Google Cloud Developers Console]

The information logged here should give you some pointers as to what is going on when AppEngine tries to serve your php page.

Comment: Okay, I understand it and I found my error. Thank you very much

Comment: unfortunately i face the same problem, but i do not have any error logs, despite the fact that i have activated error reporting in cloud console.